# Best Indexing Platforms

Tags: search, indexing, faceted-search

I've found Lucene, but what are some other indexing platforms.  Pros and Cons of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned Lucene, i'll stick with multi-faceted search:

- [Endeca](http://www.endeca.com)- is king of the commercial multi-faceted search space.  Huge commercial and government market share.  Has many modules to extend functionality. Very polished.  Expensive.  (Note: Purchased by Oracle on Dec 5th, 2011)
- [Autonomy](http://www.autonomy.com/)- Another commercial option.  Not too familiar with the product.  Link provided.
- [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (Based on Lucene) - Open source, Basic multi-faceted indexing capabilities.

Comment: Dug up another more comprehensive comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922/what-are-some-search-servers-out-there/77072#77072